# Changing Device Orientation for a particular UIViewController subclass

Tags: cocoa-touch

I want to change the device orientation when a particular view appears. I got much information on the action to be taken when the orientation changes but I am not getting how do I change the device orientation itself programatically. Note that my other views must remain in the default orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

Note that this is not part of the UIDevice framework in the API documentation, so Apple may reject an application which uses this.

Comment: This works but as @micco notes the app might be rejected.  This was confirmed by [@got nate](http://stackoverflow.com/users/145186/): 'Thank you for submitting [app name] to the App Store. Unfortunately it cannot be added to the App Store because it is using a private API. Use of non-public APIs, which as outlined in the iPhone Developer Program License Agreement section 3.3.1 is prohibited:

"3.3.1 Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs."

The non-public API that is included in your application is setOrientation:.'

Answer (score 0):

You can change the orientation of a view using `CGAffineTransforms` instead of private APIs. You have to change `UIStatusBarOrientation` orientation to match new orientation and find an angle to rotate the view:

For instance, if your view  is in landscape orientation and you want it back in portrait.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) {

    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^ {

    [view setTransform:transform];
}];

[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[view setNeedsLayout];
```